# How to add images in embedded resource file at runtime?

Tags: c#

```
Dim runTimeResourceSet As Object
    Dim dictEntry As DictionaryEntry

    runTimeResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, False, True)
    For Each dictEntry In runTimeResourceSet
        If (dictEntry.Value.GetType() Is GetType(Icon)) Then
            Console.WriteLine(dictEntry.Key)
        End If
    Next
```

Here is the code to read the embedded resource files in windows form, Is there any way to add images to the resource files at runtime??

Comment: Resource files are added to the assembly at compile time. You'll have to craft a new assembly with its resources modified. You wouldn't want to do that with your running/deployed app. Unless you are writing a tool useful mostly for developers to alter resources in their assemblies, you probably shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: Are you sure this is C#?

Answer (score 3):

[This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213445/how-to-add-image-to-resx-file-from-c-code) (right above yours) will lead you to [that post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/eeb7864b-c7c3-45fb-88c6-1d41985a0b34/), where you will find a hint to the [ResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter.addresource%28VS.80%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, take a look at the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class. Here is a tutorial on how it can be used to compile assemblies at runtime dynamically, it does now who how to add image resources but from what is there it is not hard to adapt the code to do what you ask.

[Building .NET Assemblies at Runtime](http://www.csharpfriends.com/articles/getarticle.aspx?articleid=118)